# Extend two colors bars across full width of browser?

Tags: width

I have two boxes filled with colors, a green one on the left, and gray one on the right. They go right up against each other in the middle of the screen, and I would like each one to extend the width of the browser, so the green one extends all the way to the left, and the gray one extends all the way to the right, no matter how wide the browser gets. How can I do this?

Comment: If you'd like help in fixing some piece of code, you need to show the code that you wish fixed.

Comment: show some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

the width property supports percentage values, which are relative to the size of the window it exists in.
See:
http://learnlayout.com/percent.html
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp